# How should I generate an image like this in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[Color strip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8A6e.png)

I want to generate an image like this dynamically. Is there any way to do it efficiently?

Comment: Have you tried any codes?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to write shaders? Are you new to Unity3D?

Comment: read this http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with **shaders** or generate a **texture**.

If You are new to Unity3D and shaders, it could be easier to use ***Texture2D***.

Here is a small example:

```
void Start()
 {
     // Create a new 2x2 texture ARGB32 (32 bit with alpha) and no mipmaps
     var texture = new Texture2D(2, 2, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);

     // set the pixel values
     texture.SetPixel(0, 0, new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f));
     texture.SetPixel(1, 0, Color.clear);
     texture.SetPixel(0, 1, Color.white);
     texture.SetPixel(1, 1, Color.black);

     // Apply all SetPixel calls
     texture.Apply();

     // connect texture to material of GameObject this script is attached to
     GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
 }
```

This creates a texture 2x2 pixels and sets it pixel colors.

With this you can make your own algorithm to draw pixels on a texture.
Here is reference to [Texture2D.SetPixel](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html) for using **texture**.

Also you can learn about shaders, but its a bit complex.
Here is a [SL-Reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Reference.html) about **shaders**.